# Showing programatic window a second time crashes using ARC (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: cocoa

I have some code for showing a window...

```
- (IBAction)displayWindow:(id)sender
{
    NSWindow *window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 50, 50) styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    [window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [window setAlphaValue:.5];
    [window setLevel:kShadyWindowLevel];
    [window setReleasedWhenClosed:YES];
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    self.window = window;
}
```

And to close window....

```
- (IBAction)closeWindow:(id)sender
{
    [self.window close];
}
```

and window is defined as a strong property...

```
@property (strong) NSWindow *window;
```

The code works the first time but when showing the window a second time the line...

```
self.window = window;
```

crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS...

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set "releasedWhenClosed to YES in your code. Change that to NO, and it should work fine.

Comment: I'm not using IB to create window tho as creating window programatically.

Comment: Great working now :), not sure why it works surely overwriting a object (released or not) with a new one should be ok. I guess overwriting the object Arc tries to release the object you have overwritten or something on those lines.

Comment: @rdelmar but how to fix it and leave `releasedWhenClosed == true`?